# Set data rule for mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

"When column B's value is not 3, column A's value must be null"

I want to make sure my table has this rule.

1) What is the term for this? (so I can google...)
2) How can I do this via phpMyAdmin?

Comment: you could just do an update on the table to get all current data to be correct `UPDATE table set A = NULL WHERE B <> 3` from here research [**triggers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: You would enforce this using a trigger on updates and inserts.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a `Trigger`  activated after each row that is to be modified

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_update` AFTER INSERT ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE `table` SET `columnA` = NULL WHERE `columnB` <> 3;
  END;
```